# Unable to parse authentication credentials

Tags: grafana, influxdb, nagios

I've set up an Influxdb for nagios and grafana integration I have config everything
files come in nagflux/perfdata folder
but I can't take any data on influx when I execute

```
curl -G “http://localhost:8086/query?db=nagios&pretty=true” --data-urlencode “q=show series”

“error”: “unable to parse authentication credentials”
```

I have created db “nagios” and user nagios with admin privileges.

Also in config file of influx

```
[monitor]

Whether to record statistics internally.
store-enabled = true

The destination database for recorded statistics
store-database = “nagios”

The interval at which to record statistics
store-interval = “20s”

[http]

Determines whether HTTP endpoint is enabled.
enabled = true

Determines whether the Flux query endpoint is enabled.
flux-enabled = false
The bind address used by the HTTP service.
bind-address = “:8086”

Determines whether user authentication is enabled over HTTP/HTTPS.
auth-enabled = true

The default realm sent back when issuing a basic auth challenge.
realm = “InfluxDB”

Determines whether HTTP request logging is enabled.
log-enabled = true

and in Nagflux
Main file processing configuration

[main]

#NagiosThe location of the performance data, here is the directory copied from our script

NagiosSpoolfileFolder = “/usr/local/nagflux/spool/nagfluxperfdata”

NagiosSpoolfileWorker = 1

InfluxWorker = 2

MaxInfluxWorker = 5

#File location just specify one

DumpFile = “/usr/local/nagflux/log/nagflux/nagflux.dump”

#This is the temporary storage directory of nagflux

NagfluxSpoolfileFolder = “/usr/local/nagflux”

FieldSeparator = “&”

BufferSize = 1000

FileBufferSize = 65536

#Save target we use Influxdb

DefaultTarget = “Influxdb”

#Log save settings

[Log]

LogFile = “/usr/local/nagflux/log/nagflux.log”

MinSeverity = “INFO”

#ubfluxdb global settings, mainly to allow the creation of a database

[InfluxDBGlobal]

CreateDatabaseIfNotExists = true

NastyString = “”

NastyStringToReplace = “”

HostcheckAlias = “hostcheck”

#Specify the database, NagiosPerfdata here is the database name, it will be created automatically

[InfluxDB “nagios”]

Enabled = true

Version = 1.4.2

#influxdb API interface address, the default is port 8086

Address = " http://localhost:8086 "

#Specify the user name and password here, must have administrator rights

Arguments = “precision=ms&u=nagios&p=xxxxxx&db=nagios”

StopPullingDataIfDown = true

#This configuration here is mainly to eliminate errors that have been reported in the log. If there is no livestatu$

[Livestatus]

Type = “tcp”

Version = “Icinga2”
```

The logfile of nagflux returns

```
2021-10-30 12:32:36 Info: Is InfluxDB(nagios) running: false
```

Could you please help with influx?

Answer (score 1):

Case can close the problem was at access rights of file config on file config on nagflux